# Character encoding/decoding returns ? signs or weird results when form is submitted

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, decode, utf8mb4

I know there are many similar posts about this but so far I couldn't solve my problem although I went thru them. I'm trying to print exact `search keywords` when I hit `Search` button but unfortunately I'm seeing encoded versions and I cannot decode. I read up on [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) and [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) but no luck so far. I have many languages being used in my site but I'm only struggling with the chars below.

**Note:** I'm using `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` as `collation` in MySQL and same keywords were inserted into table as `Ç, &#286;, &#304;, Ö, &#350;, Ü, ç, &#287;, &#305;, ö, &#351;, ü` so because of encoding differences, search will fail in most case.

I also have internal chars set to `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`

**SEARCH KEYWORD:** `Ç, Ğ, İ, Ö, Ş, Ü, ç, ğ, ı, ö, ş, ü`

**SITE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="search.php">
            Keyword: <input type="text" name="keywords" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**search.php**

```
var_dump($_POST);
echo $_POST['keywords'];
echo '<br />';
echo utf8_decode($_POST['keywords']);
echo '<br />';
echo iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $_POST['keywords']);
```

**OUTPUT When UTF-8 tag in  EXIST**

```
array (size=1)
      'keywords' => string 'Ã‡, Äž, Ä°, Ã–, Åž, Ãœ, Ã§, ÄŸ, Ä±, Ã¶, ÅŸ, Ã¼' (length=46)
Ã‡, Äž, Ä°, Ã–, Åž, Ãœ, Ã§, ÄŸ, Ä±, Ã¶, ÅŸ, Ã¼
Ç, ?, ?, Ö, ?, Ü, ç, ?, ?, ö, ?, ü
ÃƒÂ‡, Ã„Âž, Ã„Â°, ÃƒÂ–, Ã…Âž, ÃƒÂœ, ÃƒÂ§, Ã„ÂŸ, Ã„Â±, ÃƒÂ¶, Ã…ÂŸ, ÃƒÂ¼
```

**OUTPUT When UTF-8 tag in  REMOVED**

```
// This will also break front-end for certain characters.
array (size=1)
      'keywords' => string 'Ç, &#286;, &#304;, Ö, &#350;, Ü, ç, &#287;, &#305;, ö, &#351;, ü' (length=64)
Ç, Ğ, İ, Ö, Ş, Ü, ç, ğ, ı, ö, ş, ü
?, Ğ, İ, ?, Ş, ?, ?, ğ, ı, ?, ş, ?
Ã‡, Ğ, İ, Ã–, Ş, Ãœ, Ã§, ğ, ı, Ã¶, ş, Ã¼
```

Comment: could you `var_dump($_POST);` please?

Comment: @KimAlexander - I added it for you

Comment: so, do you see that you have mix of just characters vs html encoded charaters just in input?

Comment: Backend, frontend and DB encoding was all messed up because of many different languages. Adding `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` to `form` element sorted it. Answer is below.

Comment: check my answer, it has nothing common with your database, that is input format issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"` to form element solved the problem.

**OUTPUT**

```
array (size=1)
  'keywords' => string 'Ç, &#286;, &#304;, Ö, &#350;, Ü, ç, &#287;, &#305;, ö, &#351;, ü' (length=64)

Ç, Ğ, İ, Ö, Ş, Ü, ç, ğ, ı, ö, ş, ü
?, Ğ, İ, ?, Ş, ?, ?, ğ, ı, ?, ş, ?
Ã‡, Ğ, İ, Ã–, Ş, Ãœ, Ã§, ğ, ı, Ã¶, ş, Ã¼
```

**Note:** Whether I have `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` or not, it doesn't affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the internal encoding in PHP? mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
If both the front-end and the backend are using UTF-8, there should be no problem!

Comment: I missed to add it to the post so it is as you said. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

According to your data provided you have mixed string of just characters and html encoded characters.

So to decode them back use `html_entity_decode()` function:

```
$str = 'Ç, &#286;, &#304;, Ö, &#350;, Ü, ç, &#287;, &#305;, ö, &#351;, ü';
var_dump($str);
var_dump(html_entity_decode($str));
```

Comment: I tried this before but for some reason it causes problems to some other languages and problems when running MySQL queries. Simple solution is added above, see my answer. Thanks for your help anyway.